# Prenchimento de tabela com consulta MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, select

não traz o que quero, alguém sabe me dizer o que estou errando olhando o código?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Sistema de busca interna com PHP/MySQL</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="frmBusca" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?a=buscar" >
    <input type="text" name="palavra" />
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
</form>

<?php
// Conexão com o banco de dados
$conn = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "senha") or die("Não foi possível a conexão com o Banco");
// Selecionando banco
$db = @mysqli_select_db("produtos", $conn) or die("Não foi possível selecionar o Banco");

// Recuperamos a ação enviada pelo formulário
$a = $_GET['a'];

// Verificamos se a ação é de busca
if ($a == "buscar") {

    // Pegamos a palavra
    $palavra = trim($_POST['palavra']);

    // Verificamos no banco de dados produtos equivalente a palavra digitada
    $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE nome LIKE '%".$palavra."%' ORDER BY nome");

    // Descobrimos o total de registros encontrados
    $numRegistros = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    // Se houver pelo menos um registro, exibe-o
    if ($numRegistros != 0) {
        // Exibe os produtos e seus respectivos preços
        while ($produto = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)) {
            echo $produto->nome . " (R$ ".$produto->valor.") <br />";
        }
    // Se não houver registros
    } else {
        echo "Nenhum produto foi encontrado com a palavra ".$palavra."";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual o erro apresenta?

Comment: *"não traz o que quero"* - OK! E o que vc quer que traga? Dica: Melhore sua pergunta para evitar fechamento, saiba mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Não traz a informação, ele traz parte do código

Comment: Cole o erro, "parte do código", que está mostrando. Confira se salvou o arquivo com extensão `.php`

Comment: na tabela, deixei apenas um campo, para teste, eu queria que ele traga a como resultado o select, vamos supor, o campo se chama id_teste
ele vai fazer o select, neste caso, o resultado deveria ser 1. ele tinha que me dar este resultado neste campo do html

Comment: vou pegar o erro e deixar aqui.

Comment: eu não havia colocado o erro, porque eu queria ver se estava algo de errado no código em si, algo sem sentido, mas vou colocar o erro, só um instante.

Answer (score 0):

Tem bastante coisa errada no código, por exemplo:

a primeira é a ordem dos parametros, a correta é link e depois db_name:

```
$db = @mysqli_select_db($conn, "produtos") or die("Não foi possível selecionar o Banco");
```

segundo, ao entrar nessa pagina vai dar que $a é indefinido, pois você precisa verificar se está setado antes de atribuir, assim:

```
// Recuperamos a ação enviada pelo formulário
isset($_GET['a'])? $a = $_GET['a'] : $a = '';
```

terceiro o método do form está POST e o código PHP esperando GET esta estranho, entao precisaria mudar, mas desse jeito funciona tambem:

```
<form name="frmBusca" method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?a=buscar" >
    <input type="text" name="palavra" />
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
</form>
```

OBS: teria que criar uma outra pagina, pois mandar para a mesma certamente não é uma boa prática.

quarto o código mysqli_query, espera uma conexao por parametro:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE nome LIKE '%carro%' ORDER BY nome");
```

agora funciona, foi testado aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]